# Live USB Boot Windows 8.1

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, live-usb

So im trying to install ubuntu to dual boot windows 8.1 on my hp pavilion. It came pre installed with windows 8.1. Before i get started here please note:

---

I have tried with legacy mode on/off
I have tried it with secure boot on/off
Fast boot on/off
All combos of the above
Using Lili to burn the usb
Using Universal USB Installer
Just booting from the iso file
Yelling at the computer

---

Im using a live USB to boot into the ubuntu installer and do all that stuff but every time i try booting the usb it says "Unable to boot from the selected usb device". What am i doing wrong and how to do it right or should i just throw away windows 8.1 all together.

Also: 
Im trying to use ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Do you have a uefi bios (point and click style) I would think you do with win 8 installed, use LILI to make a USB then go to the bios and see if there is two enteries for your USB,one will say USB (or your usbs name) and UEFI, you must boot the UEFI version.

Comment: Ya ive tried booting the usb(UEFI) and it says "unable to boot from the selected usb device"

Comment: OK do you have another USB to try or a DVD

Comment: Thanks I unpacked a new USB and it work this time (maybe your magic) thanks again!

Comment: Pleasedo not forget to accept the answer this is the best thanks (press the tick on the left)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Boot windows and go to control panel and find the fast boot option turn it off (dont have win 8 too find it so have a good look)

Next in bios make your settings like this

```
> Advanced: Fast bios mode to disabled  
> Boot: Secure Boot to Disabled
> Boot: OS Mode Select left at UEFI OS (To allow Windows alongside)
> Boot: Boot device priority -> set USB HDD at top
```

Now your PC will auto boot from the USB (if it is inserted) when you reboot or it will run boot loader if not inserted.

[Here you can find a very detailed guide all about linux and UEFI](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)

Comment: Did it work ???

Answer (score 2):

Solved by OP in comments

> Thanks I unpacked a new USB and it work this time... thanks again! –  Mr.Latta

in response to this comment:

> OK do you have another USB to try or a DVD

Comment: I cannot delete because he accepted

Comment: Just up vote so it is on-top - it's Community Wiki so I won't get rep.